# Custom directives issue angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm learning angularjs thru an Apress book and one of the examples is not working properly, and I believe the issue is the custom directive, but im not sure how to debug it because my console isnt even giving me any errors.

Here are my files.

app.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- We are defining the sportStore module here in the html tag-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sports Store</title>
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <!-- Applying ng-controller to the body tagg -->
    <body  ng-app="sportsStore" ng-controller="sportsStoreCtrl">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Sports Store</a>
        <cartsummary></cartsummary>
        </div>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="data.error">
        Error ({{data.error.status}}). The product data was not loaded. <a href="/app.html" class="alert-link">Click here to try again</a>
    </div>

    <ng-include src="'views/productList.html'"></ng-include>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/sportsStore.js"></script>
    <script src="filters/customFilters.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/productListControllers.js"></script>
    <script src="components/cart/cart.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I looked at the documentation for custom directives and ive tried 
`<div cart-summary></div>`  `<cartsummary></cartsummary`> and `<cartsummary/>` (my book told me to use this one) and none appears to be working.

here is my file for the directive

cart.js

```
angular.module('cart', []).factory('cart', function() {
    var cartData = [];

    return {
        addProduct: function(id,name,price) {
            var addedToExistingItem = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < cartData.length; i++) {
                if (cartData[i].id == id) {
                    cartData[i].count++;
                    addedToExistingItem = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!addedToExistingItem) {
                cartData.push({
                    count: 1, id: id, price: price, name: name
                });
            }
        },
        removeProduct: function(id) {
            for (var i = 0; i < cartData.length; i++) {
                if (cartData[i].id == id) {
                    cartData.splice(i,1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        },
        getProducts: function() {
            return cartData;
        }
    }
}).directive('cartSummary', function(cart){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "components/cart/cartSummary.html",
        controller: function($scope) {
            var cartData = cart.getProducts();

            $scope.total = function() {
                var total = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < cartData.length; i++) {
                    total += (cartData[i].price * cartData[i].count);
                }
                return total;
            }

            $scope.itemCount = function() {
                var total = 0;
                for(var i = 0; i < cartData.length; i++) {
                    total += cartData[i].count;
                }
                return total;
            }
        }

    }
});
```

and the html file for the directive

cartSummary.html

```
<style>
    .navbar-right {float: right !important; margin-right: 5px;}
    .navbar-text {margin-right: 10px;}
</style>

<div class="navbar-right">
    <div class="navbar-text">
        <b>Your cart:</b>
        {{itemCount()}} item(s),
        {{total() | currency}}
    </div>
    <a class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Checkout</a>
</div>
```

sportsStore.js

```
//declaring a dependency called customFilters that contains a unqiue filter
angular.module('sportsStore',['customFilters', 'cart']);

// calling the angular.module method passing in sportsStore located in app.html
angular.module('sportsStore').constant('dataUrl', "http://10.0.1.51:2403/products").controller('sportsStoreCtrl', function($scope,$http,dataUrl) {
    $scope.data = {};

    $http.get(dataUrl).success(function(data) {
        $scope.data.products = data;
    }).error(function (error){
        $scope.data.error = error;
    });
});
```

Comment: @MichaelP. I just gave that a shot and nope, doesnt work :(

Comment: Do you have an error in the javascript console?

Comment: @MichaelP. no errors from the console either. Its kinda annoying debugging angularjs stuff @_@

Comment: I guessed you tried also `<cart-summary></cart-summary>` ?

Comment: @MichaelP. yes ive tried that, but nothing appears to be working. I wanna make sure we are both on the same page and the problem is coming from the custom directive right?

Comment: If you have products in the cart, but you don't see the item count and the total, then yes, the problem might be coming from the directive

Comment: @MichaelP. shouldnt angular still generate some html tho even if the code is broken? i thought that was the rule of angular to always run even if its broken

Comment: Your example is working for me : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/0m5gd04e/) I had to add a dummy product in `cartData` for testing purpose. Edit: Maybe you forgot to add `ng-app='cart'` in your home page?

Comment: @MichaelP. hmm, so weird, i copied what you did and nothing shows up for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure :

- your have the attribute `ng-app='sportsStore'` in your markup, as the directive is in the scope of the `cart` module.
- in your template, you used the syntax `<cart-summary></cart-summary>`, as the directive is named `cartSummary` and because the directive is declared as an **E**lement (cf. `restrict: 'E')`

Here is a small working fiddle with the code from your example : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/0m5gd04e/2/).

Comment: I am calling that in my sportsStore.js file, am i not?

Comment: I just looked at the `sportsStore.js` you added. It appears that the module `cart` is a dependency of the module `sportStore`. I guess in your home page you have `ng-app='sportsStore'` right?

Comment: Yes, youre correct. This is becoming such a headache and im about to delete this book thats teaching me angularjs......

Comment: If you change the value of the constant `dataUrl`, that will set `$scope.data.error = error`. Do you see the alert 'The product data was not loaded' ? I want to make sure that at least angular directives works properly.

Comment: Actually it doesn't if i change `http:10.0.1.51:2403/doesNotExist` it still loads

Answer (score -1):

Try cart-summary instead of cartsummary in app.html
Although you used the name cartSummary when defined the directive, AngularJS normalizes component names to map between these formats.